# Backslash in Jooq/PostgreSQL INSERT clause

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I am trying to use Jooq to do an INSERT into a PostgreSQL database. The query fails if the String includes a backslash character with SQL state code: 42601 which means SYNTAX ERROR.

- Jooq: 3.4.4
- postgresql driver: 8.4-702.jdbc4
- PostgreSQL: "PostgreSQL
  8.4.20 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 64-bit"
- JDK 1.8.0_25
- Spring Tool Suite 3.6.0.RELEASE

**Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE datahub.test (
    body TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

**Jooq code generated using maven:**

- jooq-codegen-maven version 3.4.4
- generator.name: org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator
- generator.database.name: org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase

**Unit test**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/spring-config.xml"})
public class BatchExceptionJooqTest {
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(BatchExceptionJooqTest.class);
    @Autowired
    private DSLContext db;
    @Test
    public void runBasicJooqTest(){
        try{
            final List<InsertQuery<TestRecord>> batchUpdate = Lists.newLinkedList();
            InsertQuery<TestRecord> insertQuery = db.insertQuery(TEST);
            insertQuery.addValue(TEST.BODY, "It's a bit more complicated than just doing copy and paste... :\\");
            batchUpdate.add(insertQuery);
            db.batch(batchUpdate).execute();
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

The test fails with an exception:

2014-12-26 17:11:16,490 [main] ERROR  BatchExceptionJooqTest:36  :runBasicJooqTest               - org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [null]; Batch entry 0 insert into "datahub"."test" ("body") values ('It''s a bit more complicated than just doing copy and paste... :\') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.

The test passes, if instead of String: `"It's a bit more complicated than just doing copy and paste... :\\"` I use String: `"It's a bit more complicated than just doing copy and paste... :\\\\"`. This seems a bit inconsistent when compared to what is happening to the the single quote during the operation. It is correctly doubled so as to get through the SQL parser. Not so with the backslash.

I read somewhere that escaping a backslash with another backslash is not part of the SQL standard and Postgre has changed its default behavior lately. However I am not clear on the meaning of the [manual p 4.1.2.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) - it seems to indicate that double backslashes should work and there is not really any reason for jooq not to do it.

So.. could someone please explain if the described situation in Jooq:

1. Is desired behavior and there is no workaround besides doubling all incoming backslashes my application is processing?
2. Is desired behavior but there is a configuration change I can do to make Jooq process the backslashes in a similar manner to the single quotes?
3. Is it a bug?
4. What am I doing incorrectly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PostgreSQL 8.x. In that version, the system defaulted to accepting backslash escaped string literals even without the preceding `E`.

To avoid this, you should set the server configuration variable `standard_conforming_strings` to `ON`.

It is, of course, strongly recommended that you migrate to a version of PostgreSQL higher than 8.x, as the 8.x versions have reached end-of-life and are no longer supported.

Comment: Would this Postgre side flag actually influence the way Jooq formats the parameter string it sends to the database? The thing which is the strangest is that Jooq formats the single quotations but not the backslashes.

Comment: @Tarmo: jOOQ doesn't explicitly support PostgreSQL 8.x with all the quirks that existed back when that version was fresh. In other words, jOOQ is unaware of this particular behaviour.

Comment: Lukas Eder is right. As far as jOOQ is concerned, a backslash inside a string is not a special character. By turning the configuration option I mentioned on, you make PostgreSQL 8.x forward-compatible with current versions.

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ 3.5 has introduced `org.jooq.conf.Settings.backslashEscaping` (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3000). This was mainly introduced for MySQL, which still today defaults to non-standards compliant string literal escaping using backslashes.

Note that this setting affects only inlined bind values, so it will not escape backslashes when binding values to a `PreparedStatement`.

I agree with [RealSkeptic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27663026/521799), which suggests you change the database behaviour or upgrade to a newer PostgreSQL version.